# Real integral with residue theorem. Where am I wrong?

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I have a simple integral to compute with the residue theorem, but since it has been a while since I have solved integrals with this method I am a bit confused.

The integral I have to calculate is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{(e^{iqr}-e^{-iqr})}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq$

$r, \xi$ are both greater than $0$ and real numbers.

The first thing I want to do is to split the difference into two integrals:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{e^{iqr}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{e^{-iqr}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq$

After that, I have tried to compute the first integral using residue theorem:

the two singularities, which are the same also for the second integral, are $z_1=i\xi^{-1}$ and $z_2=-i\xi^{-1}$. Now I have to compute the first residue for $z_1$, which turns out to be $Res(f(z),z_1)=\frac{e^{-r/\xi}}{2}$, while the second residue is $Res(f(z),z_2)=\frac{e^{r/\xi}}{2}$.

With this done, hopefully without errors, I don't remember how to go on. For the first singularity, I think I have to close the path upwards while I have to do the same thing but downward, but do I have to change signs?

What I get as a final result is:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{e^{iqr}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq=2\pi i(\frac{e^{-r/\xi}}{2}+\frac{e^{r/\xi}}{2})$

and the same for the second integral but with a minus sign in front of it. The result is obviously wrong, I think the right result is $2\pi ie^{-r/\xi}$.

Where am I wrong? I avoided all the arguments on the circular paths etc., because I'm not interested in a rigorous mathematical threatment, I just want to be able to do the integral. I think what I'm getting wrong are the signs, I don't remember if I have to change signs when I close the path in order to include $z_2$.

Comment: Are there any restrictions concerning $r$ or $\xi$?

Comment: You say "The result is obviously wrong". Why?

Comment: You should specify a closed contour to integrate on.  Then check that the integrals on the parts you don't want go to zero.  Perhaps your contour surrounds one of the poles but not the other?

Comment: @GEdgar yes, my countour surrounds one of the poles but not the other, I'm wondering how should I do in this case. I think I have to consider 2 contours, but don't know how

Comment: @AnotherUser They're both >0, I forgot.

Comment: @jjagmath Because in the way I'm doing it, I get 0.

Comment: When you construct a contour, you shouldn't worry about having all the poles in that contour. The main goal is to just have a closed contour that connects with whichever line has the interval you are integrating on (assuming there are no divergence issues). Whichever poles lie in it and which ones don't is irrelevant.

Comment: A related method... $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{(e^{iqr}-e^{-iqr})}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{2i\sin(qr)}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq= 2\operatorname{Im}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q\frac{\exp(iqr)}{q^2+\xi^{-2}} \,dq$$ so you only have to do one of the integrals.

Comment: For the first (second) integral, use a semicircle in the upper (lower) half plane; either way, only one pole is enclosed. If this is unfamiliar, do $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$ the same way first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to use the following

**Theorem:** Let $P$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, let $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus P\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function such that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$, and let $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Then
\begin{multline}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iaz}f(z)\,dz=\\
=2\pi i\times\begin{cases}\text{sum of the residues of $f$ on those $\eta\in P$ with }\operatorname{Im}\eta>0&\text{ if }a>0\\-\text{sum of the residues of $f$ on those $\eta\in P$ with }\operatorname{Im}\eta<0&\text{ if }a<0.\end{cases}
\end{multline}

Concerning the first integral: since $r>0$, the theorem says that the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty q\frac{e^{iqr}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}}\,dq.
$$
is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $q\frac {e^{irq}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}}$ on the upper half-plane. It has only one residue there, located at $\frac i\xi$, and the value of that residue is $\frac12e^{-r/\xi}$. So, the integral of this function is equal to $\pi ie^{-r/\xi}$.

Now, since $-r<0$, the theorem also says that the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty q\frac{e^{-iqr}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}}\,dq.
$$
is equal to *minus* the sum of the residues of $q\frac {e^{-irq}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}}$ on the *lower* half-plane. The function has only one residue there, located it $-\frac i\xi$, and the value of that residue is, again, $\frac12e^{-r/\xi}$. Therefore, the integral of this function is equal to $-\pi ie^{-r/\xi}$. So,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty q\frac{e^{iqr}-e^{-iqr}}{q^2+\xi^{-2}}\,dq=2\pi ie^{-r/\xi}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, so once I choose one of the paths, lower half-plane or upper half-plane, I don't have to consider the other residue. Another question, if I compute the second integral choosing again the upper half-plane, I get as the residue $\pi i e^{r/\xi}$ and then the whole integral is equal to $\pi i (e^{-r/\xi}-e^{r/\xi})$. Where is the wrong part here?

Comment: The reason for using the lower half-plane on the second integral is: as $R \to \infty$ the integrand goes to zero on a semicircle of radius $R$ in the lower half-plane.  But that is not true for semicircle in the upper half-plane.  So it is important to actually write down the contour, and to check what happens on the parts to be discarded (here, the large semicircles).  So I think the "Another User" answer is incomplete.

Comment: You misunderstood what I wrote. *I made no choice whatsoever.*

Comment: I used this classical Complex Analysis theorem, which states that if $P$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, if $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus P\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function such that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$, and if $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, then$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iaz}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\times\begin{cases}\text{sum of residues of $f$ on those $\eta\in P$ such that }\operatorname{Im}\eta>0&\text{ if }a>0\\-\text{sum of residues of $f$ on those $\eta\in P$ such that }\operatorname{Im}\eta<0&\text{ if }a<0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: @GEdgar After reading my previous comment, do you still think that my answer is incomplete?

Comment: Your answer (not mentioning the theorem) is incomplete in my opinion.  Adding the theorem to the answer would make it a fine solution.

Comment: @GEdgar I agree and I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The answer could be improved even more with a reference to the theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar I've done it.